# pga gain formula

Tags: gain, programmable-gain-amplifier

Background: I am dealing with reverse engineering a software. And trying to understand a formula in the code.

I found a formula that reads:

```
pga_gain = pow (10.0, agc / 20.0);
```

In the above formula what are 10.0 and 20.0. 10 seems to be the log10 base. Is that correct? In any case I would appreciate if someone could give me the names of those magic numbers in that formula.

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is almost certainly a conversion between dB, and linear gain.

pga_gain (linear) = 10**(agc/20) (with agc expressed in dB)

When going the other way, the formula is gain(dB) = 20 * log10(linear_gain)

Read all about dB units [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel). In summary, Bell Labs started using powers of 10, which were too big to be convenient, so now we use deciBells, or dB. A rather better article pointed out by Curd in his comment is [this one](http://www.rohde-schwarz.de/file_5613/1MA98_4E.pdf).

The multiplier is 10 for power ratio, and 20 for the voltage ratio. When you are measuring amplifier or attenuator gain, you use voltage ratio.

Comment: So the 20 here is an arbitrary number? I would like to name it in my code. If it is arbitrary please suggest a name. Twenty log multiplier, perhaps?

Comment: Added a link to where you can read all about dB.

Comment: 20 comes from the definition of a decibel.

Comment: Another link to a document about "dB or not dB": www.rohde-schwarz.de/file_5613/1MA98_4E.pdf